# Weather application

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

everyone

Okay, so I'm creating a weather application that takes the information from the yahoo weather api. Here is the XML: http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=44310

p.s. it is better to open it inside Google Chrome since it'll display it as a XML file.

I'm trying to take multiple items from the XML. I'm trying to make the information display the full city and state, but how would I do that?

The XML is for my area, but I'm going to need it to work with any city.

Here is my code:

```
public class PanelBase extends libs.PanelBase
{
    private var vo:WeatherVO;
    private var _details:DetailsView;

    public function PanelBase()
    {
        super();

        // below is my settings for the input area where you have to enter your zip code
        // .text empties the field, .restrict keeps a person from using what ever 
        // is not added. in this case, the person can only use numbers from 0 to 9 only
        // .maxchars sets the number of possible items that a person can enter inside the input field.
        // buttonMode just creates the illusion of a button formed from a graphic
        this.tf_Zipcode.text = "";
        this.tf_Zipcode.restrict = "0-9";
        this.tf_Zipcode.maxChars = 5;
        this.btn_Enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processZip);
    }

    // function for the button
    private function processZip(e:Event):void
    {
        // if the zip code area is wrong, inside of the text area above the zip code
        // will let you know that the zip entered is wrong, but if the zip code
        // you enter has less than 5 numbers, then you will be told there aren't enough numbers
        // then the zip code text field will empty itself.
        if(this.tf_Zipcode.text == null)
        {
            this.tf_Hint.text = "Sorry! Your zip code is invalid.";
        }
        else if(this.tf_Zipcode.text.length < 5)
        {
            this.tf_Zipcode.text = "";
            this.tf_Hint.text = "There are not enough numbers!"
        }
        else
        {
            this.removeChild(this.tf_Zipcode);
            this.addChild(this.tf_Zipcode);
            this.tf_Zipcode.text = "";
            //getImages();
            loadInfo();
        }
    }

    // function for loading the XML
    private function loadInfo():void
    {
        var ld:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        ld.load(new URLRequest("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=44310&u=f"));
        ld.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseInfo);
    }

    // function 
    private function parseInfo(e:Event):void
    {
        var xmlData:XML = XML(e.target.data);
        var ns1:Namespace = new Namespace("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");
        var ns2:Namespace = new Namespace("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");

        // parsing the information from the XML into the text fields 
        vo = new WeatherVO();
        vo.City = xmlData.channel.ns1::location.@city;
        vo.CurrentTemp = xmlData.channel.ns1::condition.@temp;
        vo.High = xmlData.item.channel.ns1::forecast.@high;
        vo.Low = xmlData.item.channel.ns1::forecast.@low;
        vo.Humidity = xmlData.channel.ns1::atmosphere.@humidity;
        vo.Wind = xmlData.channel.ns1::wind.@chill;
        vo.Rise = xmlData.channel.ns1::astronomy.@sunrise;
        vo.Set = xmlData.channel.ns1::astronomy.@sunset;
        vo.Tomorrow = xmlData.channel.item.ns2::forecast[1].@day;


        trace(xmlData)
        updateTextFields();

    }

    private function updateTextFields():void
    {
        //remove zip code view and then add result panel view


        _details = new DetailsView();
        this.addChild(_details);

        _details.tf_City.text = vo.City;
        _details.tf_CurrentTemp.text = vo.CurrentTemp;
        _details.tf_High.text = vo.High;
        _details.tf_Low.text = vo.Low;
        _details.tf_Humidity.text = vo.Humidity;
        _details.tf_Wind.text = vo.Wind;
        _details.tf_Rise.text = vo.Rise;
        _details.tf_Set.text = vo.Set;
        _details.tf_Tomorrow.text = vo.Tomorrow;
```

Comment: dude, you need to be more specific about exactly you want to do. what is not working? errors?

Comment: No, no errors, I just need to know how to get more than one piece of information from the XML. I said I wanted it to say for example: Akron OH. I'm only getting Akron. When you click on the link given, you will see the XML. The area where I'm parsing the information is where the problem lies. How do you grab more than one piece of information from the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your parseInfo method:

```
vo.Region = xmlData.channel.ns1::location.@region;

trace (vo.City + ", " + vo.Region);
```

Comment: As a side note, I recommend Google's Weather API:

[http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Akron](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Akron)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been online till now. Thank you, I'll try Google's API since Yahoo's version doesn't quite work well for me. Also, your idea could work since I could just add a second text area to my design and just add the region that way. Thanks again.

Comment: I have a question, Michael how would I enter the right address in my code inside the ld.load(new URLRequest(""))? Would I need the namespace variables as well? I don't see and URIs anywhere inside Google's API. Thanks.

Comment: For Google's API, its just http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Paris+France it will do its best to figure out what/where it is you want weather info for. For instance you can use a zipcode, city/state, etc. Google's shouldn't need any namespaces, so you can just use the data from the XMLData you parsed using Google's explicit XML output.

Comment: For the City/Region, just use:

`city_region_textfield_name.text = vo.City +", "+ vo.Region;` it should input "Akron, OH" to the textField, or with google's api, simply return the city data.

Comment: Everything seems to be working. Do you have any idea how I could make this work with what ever zip code is typed into the text field? What about getting the images to show? I have a movie clip named "CurrentTempPic" which I added earlier today. I stuck with the Yahoo API for this one.

Comment: Just stick tf_Zipcode.text at the end of your URLRequest:

`ld.load(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" + tf_Zipcode.text);`

Comment: When I add the tf_Zipcode.text at the end my XML shows like this: <channel>
    <title>Yahoo! Weather - Error</title>
    <description>Yahoo! Weather Error</description>
    <item>
      <title>City not found</title>
      <description>Invalid Input /forecastrss?p=</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>

Comment: I misunderstood, I'm sorry, I thought you had used the Google API and were using Yahoo's for the images. You will need an AppID from [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/wsregapp), then you will make two calls, one to http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q(90210)?appid= where 90210 is the zip code to get the WOEID of the city and use that to call http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12765532 where the numbers are the WOEID. The "p" parameter has been depreciated as stated [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#params).

Comment: If you do want to use the p though, take a look at your code here:  
  
`this.tf_Zipcode.text = "";
            //getImages();
            loadInfo();`  
  
You clear out the zip field instance, add it back in, and make sure its empty before calling the loadInfo function. If that is required for UI purposed, store the value before clearing it out. tempZip = tf_Zipcode.text, then use tempZip instead of tf_Zipcode. I hope this helps a bit more, if you get stuck, I can be reached at the email in my profile.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, you have been a really great help. I'll test out the advise given later today. It's like 3:28AM here so, I'm in relax mode; programming is stressful when you're still new to it. If only there were tutors for this stuff because I would love to get really good at programming. Thanks again, and I'll send you a message if I do run into a problem.